# How to make a REST API chrome extension

Tags: rest, api, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension that uses REST API. This extension should receive `word` fields in address `https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml=book`.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by reading how to develop Chrome extensions [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions).

"Extensions are small software programs that can modify and enhance the functionality of the Chrome browser. You write them using web technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

A screenshot of an extension's icon in the browser bar Extensions have little to no user interface. For example, the image to the right shows the icon that provides the UI for the Google Mail Checker extension.

Extensions bundle all their files into a single file that the user downloads and installs. This bundling means that, unlike ordinary web apps, extensions don't need to depend on content from the web.

You can distribute your extension using the Chrome Developer Dashboard to publish to the Chrome Web Store. For more information, see the store developer documentation. "

Comment: I know how to develop Chrome extensions. But can't find about rest API.

Comment: Which bit of rest are you struggling with?  It's a simple http call and response.

Comment: does not answer the question